# Generating a rails migration, how can I get the migration filename into my clipboard automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, macos, shell

I'd like to have rails make my new migration available for editing or viewing immediately after I've created it.

Is there a neat way to put the new `db/migrations/timestamp_migration_name.rb`straight into my clipboard, or open up in my editor?

I'm interested in Osx or Linux methods of doing this, windows methods would be a bonus for other people.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way to do this in each, (Windows requires you are using rails command line from cygwin for this)

For OSX to clipboard

```
rails g migration add_something_to_table | grep -oP 'db\/.*\.rb' | pbcopy
```

For any linux + X

```
rails g migration add_something_to_table | grep -oP 'db\/.*\.rb' | xclip
```

For Windows (with cygwin)

```
rails g migration add_something_to_table | grep -oP 'db\/.*\.rb' > /dev/clipboard
```